# how to extract substring from file with multiple lines

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to extract the OS name from /etc/os-release which contains:

```
...
NAME="Os Name"
...
```

But when I execute:

```
sed 's/.*NAME="\([^"]*\).*/\1/' /etc/os-release
```

It correctly capture the Os Name, but it prints all the other lines intead of printing only the captured string, why?

Content of os-release file

```
cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Sed command that should output only "CentOS Linux" but it outputs all the lines:

```
$ sed 's/.*NAME="\([^"]*\).*/\1/' /etc/os-release
CentOS Linux
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `-n` option to suppress regular output and `/p` mode in `s` command to print the result on a particular line:

```
sed -nE 's/^NAME="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' /etc/os-release

CentOS Linux
```

You can also use awk:

```
awk -F '["=]+' '$1=="NAME"{print $2}' /etc/os-release

CentOS Linux
```

Or using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP '^NAME="\K[^"]+' /etc/os-release
```

Comment: Because you're not using `-n` option of `sed` to suppress regular output.

Comment: But here [http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html] says `By default, sed prints every line. If it makes a substitution, the new text is printed instead of the old one`, so it should only print the string saved in \1, no? Does sed runs independently in every line?

Comment: yeah, it seems that sed works line by line http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `sed` for this. Just `grep` and `cut` should do it.

```
$ grep "^NAME=" /etc/os-release | cut -d\= -f2
```